# Joint distribution of continuous and discrete variables

Tags: probability

Consider the following experiment: We sort $X \sim U(0,1)$ and if $X = x$ we sort a r.b Bernoulli($x$). Can we find the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?

I know that the random CDF is:
$$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$$

thus $$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, y =  0) + P(X \leq x, y =1)$$

but how can i go on and finish it? Can i find the pdf after this or there ir some restrition? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If $X \sim U (0, 1) ; Y \sim Bern (x)$, then  $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = x^y (1-x)^{(1-y)}$

Comment: Ok, but this is the density, how can i find the joint distribution?